# É possível enviar múltiplas requisições de forma rápida em Java, de forma síncrona?

Tags: java, api, http-request

Implementei uma API que recebe `n` mensagens de uma fila, em uma mensageria. Capturo dois parâmetros que são enviados para uma requisição, na qual retorna um JSON com certos elementos para eu montar um objeto específico e salvar em um banco de dados.

Ou seja, para `n` mensagens da fila, preciso enviar `n` requisições de maneira implementada a seguir:

```
public static String sendRequest(String urlParam, String token) {

        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlParam);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("portaltokenhom", token);
            conn.setRequestProperty("flgRetornoPadrao", "0");

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String linha;
            while ((linha = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(linha);
            }
            in.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RequestException("Erro ao realizar requisição para rota " + urlParam, e.getCause());
        }
        return response.toString();
    }
```

Então, em algum momento terei que ler 130.000 mensagens da fila e enviar 130.000 requisições para salvar 130.000 objetos no banco de dados... Sabendo que é inviável, porém, é o modelo dado pelo cliente.

Portanto, é possível enviar múltiplas requisições de maneira rápida e eficiente no Java 8?

Comment: "*de maneira síncrona*" fica, necessariamente, preso ao tempo de resposta da API, então o "*de maneira rápida*" dependerá muito mais da API do que do seu código.

Comment: É pq eu preciso somente armazenar o resultado do JSON de alguma forma, então, acredito que realizando de maneira assíncrona também seria possível. Há algum modo?